# CSS drop down menu is not working as expected

Tags: css, html, css-position

when I make the div's(that contains the drop down menu)positioning to relative and the drop down menu div's positioning to absolute,it shows me only the last item on the drop down menu.if I set drop down menu container div to relative and leave the drop down menu div positioning,then it works.But that affects the rest of the page.So,how to set the positioning that would make the drop down works without affecting any other parts of the page.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="top_head">
  My Online Shop
    <div id="nav">
      <div class="test"><a href="home.php">Home</a></div>
      <div class="test" id="product"><a href="produt.php">Products</a>
           <div class="test1"><a href="about.php">shirt</a></div>
           <div class="test1"><a href="about.php">Pant</a></div>
           <div class="test1"><a href="about.php">inner</a></div>
           <div class="test1"><a href="about.php">cap</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="test"><a href="about.php">About</a></div>
      <div class="test"><a href="contact.php">contact Us</a></div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
   color:green;
}
#top_head{
   width:100%;
   height:100px;
   font:48px Arial green;
   border:1px dotted red;

}
#nav{
   background-color:gray;
   width:57%;
   border-radius:5px;
   font:28px Arial orange;
   margin:0px -49px 5px 15px;
}
#nav a{
   color:red;
   text-decoration:none;
   margin:0px 50px;
}
.test{
   float:left;
}
.test:hover{
   background-color:orange;
}
#product{
   position:relative;
}
.test1{
   position:absolute;
   border:1px solid red;
   visibility:hidden;
}
   #product:hover .test1{
   visibility:visible;
   background-color:yellow;
}
```

I've tried with display property too. Same results.
If you have any idea where the problem lies, please help.

Comment: Why aren't you using `ul`s and `li`s? And why not use [one of the many that have been made already?](https://www.google.com/search?q=pure+css+drop+down+menu+cross+browser&oq=pure+css+drop+do&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.3757j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Please put together a jsfiddle to help see the problem better.

Comment: _“it shows me only the last item on the drop down menu”_ – of course this happens, because you absolutely position _all_ of the `.test1` elements, but without specifying a different `top` value for each – so they all end up on top of each other. If you were to implement this in a _sensible_ way using lists as @ZachSaucier suggested, then you would not have that problem, because you would only have to position the list that contains all the sub-menu items, so the items themselves could flow normally and wouldn’t lay on top of each other.

Comment: And yes, this topic has been covered in all epic breadth on the net already, so please do some proper research and adopt one of the numerous existing solutions. SO is not the place to teach you CSS _basics_ after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue here is that you're using `position:absolute` on all of the sub menu divs. This is essentially making them lay on top of each other (leaving the last one on top).

One solution for this is to wrap all of these elements in a container div and make that the thing that is hidden or shown:

**[Working Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wqYA9/)**

Your sub-menu becomes:

```
 <div class="test1">
   <div><a href="about.php">shirt</a></div>
   <div><a href="about.php">Pant</a></div>
   <div><a href="about.php">inner</a></div>
   <div><a href="about.php">cap</a></div>
 </div>
```

And the CSS is altered slightly:

```
.test1{
  display:none;
}

.test1 div{
   border:1px solid red;
}

#product:hover .test1{
 position:absolute;
 display: block;
 background-color:yellow;
}
```